# Displaying a hierarchical list with child node in every row using Angular and also in Java

Tags: java, json, angularjs, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchical list as shown below.

```
 FriendList c = 
 [ 
{
    name:"A", 
    nickname:"a", 
    children:[
        {
            name:"A1", 
            nickname:"a1", 
            children:[] 
        },
        {
            name:"A2", 
            nickname:"a2", 
            children:[ 
                {
                    name:"A21", 
                    nickname:"a21", 
                    children:[] 
                },
                {
                    name:"A22", 
                    nickname:"a22", 
                    children:[] 
                },
                {
                    name:"A23", 
                    nickname:"a23", 
                    children:[ 
                        {
                            name:"A231", 
                            nickname:"a231", 
                            children:[] 
                        }             
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name:"A3", 
            nickname:"a3", 
            children:[] 
        },
        {
            name:"A4", 
            nickname:"a4", 
            children:[ 
                {
                    name:"A41", 
                    nickname:"a41", 
                    children:[] 
                }
            ]
        }
    ] 
}
]
```

I need to display this data using Javascript/ AngularJS on browser and also using Java to generate PDF in the following way:

```
  parent_name     parent_nickname      child_name      child_nickname

    A                 a                  A1                 a1
    A                 a                  A2                 a2
    A2                a2                 A21                a21
    A2                a2                 A22                a22
    A2                a2                 A23                a23
    A23               a23                A231               a231
    A                 a                  A3                 a3
    A                 a                  A4                 a4
    A4                a4                 A41                a41
```

I can use the idea given in

[stack overflow displaying hierarchical list as flat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212915/traversing-through-a-hierarchy-to-display-items-as-list-in-java)

But it displays the structure with first two columns only.

Comment: Why you duplicated your questions , discussing under that answer might be more helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Traversing through a hierarchy to display items as list in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212915/traversing-through-a-hierarchy-to-display-items-as-list-in-java)